# How to remotely use Ubuntu software center

Tags: software-center, software-installation

my sysadmin set up my work machine such that I don't have root privilege but I can  use ubuntu software center to install packages by providing my password.

I login to that Ubuntu machine **remotely**, and I'd like to install some packages from the software center, how can I do this?

I tried "software-center" , which gives me the interface, but nothing happens when I click on "install"

NOTE: both machines involved are ubuntu machine.

This post might help understand my situation, my sys-admin did the same thing. I don't know how he/she implemented it.

Thank you in advance.

---

my sys-admin say that the software-center cannot go through X-forwarding, so I cannot install via software center using ssh. But I will try the remote desktop thing.

Thank you all for inputs!

Comment: Does using `sudo` work (e.g. `sudo echo 1`)? Also, from what sort of machine do you want to remotely access the software center?

Comment: hello, I don't have sudo priviledge.

Comment: just checking, as most answers like hwez's won't work...

Comment: Thanks, I tried "sudo echo 1", returns " you are not in the sudoers file" so I guess I can't sodu. Both machines are ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use team viewer

For the 32-bit package:

```
$ wget http://download.teamviewer.com/download/teamviewer_linux.deb
$ sudo dpkg -i teamviewer_linux.deb
```

For the 64-bit package:

```
$ wget http://download.teamviewer.com/download/teamviewer_linux_x64.deb
$ sudo dpkg -i teamviewer_linux_x64.deb
```

& Install it on the other pc that you are wanting to control with 
connect by the id & password

Comment: if the user does not have root access, sudo might not work... However, the package cmight be installable with software center (just download it and click on it). Help for teamviewer is available [here](http://www.teamviewer.com/en/help/firststeps.aspx).

Comment: you can't install any package without root access

Comment: The remote system is set up such that I can install software from software-center but I don't have sudo .

Comment: oh sorry you can open teamviewer_linux.deb in  software-center

Answer (score 0):

Installing/removing software requires root privileges - so when you don't have `sudo` access you should not be able to install software with the software-center or any other system-method, even if you were sitting at the machine.

I am not aware of a simple method to enable you to install software via software-center that doesn't involve giving you (restricted) `sudo` access.

Ask your system administrator to allow you to use software-center for installing/removing software when you access the system remotely too - he must approve/deny anyway.

Comment: thanks for you help, but I don't think you understand my question.